# Encrypt credentials in web.config possible

Tags: encryption, credentials

I have this section of my web.config file.

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx">
      <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
        <user name="test@hotmail.com" password="12345" />
      </credentials>
    </forms>
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

I have tried to encrypt this section, but I get the object not set to an instance of the object error. This is the path that I called in the encryption class: system.web/authentication/forms/credentials

Any solution please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IIS, make sure your site ID in IIS is set to 1 (Advanced settings).